# How to upload values to a website and select a button using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate the sending of SMSes from a company website but I do not know how to upload the message, the cellphone number and select the button to send the message.

[image: Message Code]
[image: Cell number Code]
[image: Button Select Code]

```vb
Sub smssend()

      Dim appIE As Object
      Dim e As Object
      Dim wb As Workbook
      Dim ws As Worksheet
      Dim cellno As String
      Dim mess As String
      Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^((?:\+27|0[0-9]{9}"
      Dim regEx As New RegExp
      Dim linecount As Long
      
      linecount = 2
      
      
      Set wb = Application.Workbooks("SMSmacro")
      Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
      
      
      Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
     With appIE
        .navigate "http://cadde.abgza.co.za/SMS/CreateSMS/CreateSms"
        Do While appIE.busy
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        Loop
        .Visible = True
        
    End With
        Do While appIE.busy
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        Loop
      
    Do While ws.Cells(linecount, 1) <> ""
    cellno = ws.Cells(linecount, 1)
    mess = ws.Cells(linecount, 2)
    a = Len(mess)
    If Len(mess) > 160 Then
    
    ws.Cells(linecount, 4).Value = "Message Too Long"
    GoTo nxt
    End If
    
    With regEx
            
    If regEx.Test(cellno) Then
        With appIE
        Set e = appIE.document.getElementById("cellNumber")
        e = cellno
        End With
    Else
        ws.Cells(linecount, 3).Value = "Incorrect Cell Number"
    End If
    End With
    nxt:
    linecount = linecount + 1
    Loop
    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten your code. Never use `GoTo`, except for error handling.

The three variables `nodeCellNo`, `nodeMess` and `nodeSubBut` are not mandatory. I have introduced them to make the code more comprehensible for you. Without variables you can access a node directly this way:
`appIE.document.getElementById("cellNumber").Value = cellNo`

I can't tell from your HTML code whether the change event of the textarea tag needs to be triggered to recognize the text of the message.

Please read the comments in the code carefully:

```
Sub SendSMS()
  'If you have constant values use constants in your code
  Const url As String = "http://cadde.abgza.co.za/SMS/CreateSMS/CreateSms"
  Const strPattern As String = "^((?:\+27|0[0-9]{9}"
  
  'If you use late binding, no Excel reference is required
  'Advantage: The code runs immediately on every computer
  'Disadvantage: No IntelliSense is available during programming
  Dim appIE As Object
  Dim nodeCellNo As Object
  Dim nodeMess As Object
  Dim nodeSubBut As Object
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim cellNo As String
  Dim mess As String
  Dim regEx As Object 'Changed to late binding
  Dim currentRow As Long
  
  'Initialize variables
  currentRow = 2
  Set wb = Application.Workbooks("SMSmacro.xlsm") 'Full name needed
  Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  'Use the following line if you are in an intranet and
  'the IE lost connection to the remote server
  'Set appIE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
  
  'Load page to IE
  appIE.Visible = True
  appIE.navigate url
  Do While appIE.busy: DoEvents: Loop
  'The following line is only needed if the web page loads dynamic
  'content after IE has reported that it is no longer busy
  'The length of the break can be adjusted to your needs
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
  
  'If the page looks like the SMS sending page after sending,
  'the loop can start here. If another page is loaded, one
  'could navigate again within the loop to the SMS URL. For
  'many SMS I would set the loop further up and restart IE
  'for each SMS. Unfortunately, if you navigate a lot in one
  'instance of IE, it becomes unstable.
  Do While ws.Cells(currentRow, 1) <> ""
    cellNo = ws.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value
    mess = ws.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value
    
    If Len(mess) > 160 Then
      ws.Cells(currentRow, 4).Value = "Message Too Long"
    Else
      If regEx.Test(cellNo) Then
        'Insert cellphone number to html form
        Set nodeCellNo = appIE.document.getElementById("cellNumber")
        nodeCellNo.Value = cellNo
        
        'Insert message to html form
        'The textarea tag has no value attribute
        'You can set the text by innertext to set it
        'between the opening and the closing tectarea tag
        Set nodeMess = appIE.document.getElementById("typedMessage")
        nodeMess.innertext = mess
        
        'Click submit button
        Set nodeSubBut = appIE.document.getElementById("btnSend")
        nodeSubBut.Click
        
        'Wait to send the SMS
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
      Else
        ws.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = "Incorrect Cell Number"
      End If
    End If
    
    'Next SMS
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: you are a scholar and gentleman. Works well with the intranet setAppIE